# Python : looking for items from a list that exist in another list

Tags: python

I want to calculate the bias between two curves but I have values of the first curve that are not in the second curve. So, I try to eliminate the values of the first curve that are not defined by the second curve. How will I proceed? Thank you for answering me.

Comment: Show us the code you're working with.

Comment: these are two curves that represent a physical parameter as a function of time. and this is one of the time series that I want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your values in 2 lists:

```
new_values = [val for val in list1 if val not in list2]
```